# Spark 2.1 : How to provide multiple columns in DataFrameWriter partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to create an orc file with multiple partitions using Spark 2.1. My code looks like so:
`df.write.option("compression", "zlib").partitionBy("a, b").orc("s3a://bucket/")`

where `a` & `b` are two columns on which I want to partition by.

I'm stuck with `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Partition column "a, b" not found in schema`!

I tried several combinations in `partitionBy` like `'a, b'` or `'a', 'b'` ... nothing works? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So, i found the problem! And for the person who voted it down, please note: the order of functions is important for multiple partitions to work! first comes `partitionBy` and then comes the others. So this works:
`df.write.partitionBy("a", "b").option("compression", "zlib").orc("s3a://bucket/")`! Just that, from documentation it is not obvious, and nowhere in documentation or other answers on the web, is this obvious!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, i found the problem! And for the person who voted it down, please note: the order of functions is important for multiple partitions to work! first comes `partitionBy` and then comes the others. So this works: `df.write.partitionBy("a", "b").option("compression", "zlib").orc("s3a://bucket/")`! Just that, from documentation it is not obvious, and nowhere in documentation or other answers on the web, is this obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.write.option("compression", "zlib").partitionBy("a", "b").orc("s3a://bucket/")
```

Maybe this can help.

Comment: I tried that too, did not work! Please see my answer. Thanks.